# how do I get ID from salesforce URL in my controller.Also please provide the solution if I am sending multiple id via url

Tags: apex

I have an button called "button3_AddAttachment" in search layout.
Code:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/apex.js")} 

var records = {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.Bank__c)}; 

if(records=='')
{
 alert('Please select a record');

}
else if(records!='')
{
  window.top.location="/apex/test5_MultipleFileUpload"+"?id="+records;

}
```

When I select multiple record in search layout page and click the button it will redirect to "test5_MultipleFileUpload" visualforce page with the selected record ids.

URL Example:
https://c.ap4.visual.force.com/apex/test5_MultipleFileUpload?id=a046F00001eoknq%2Ca046F00001eokoU

---

a046F00001eoknq and a046F00001eokoU are two record ids 
I want to capture the ids and pass it to my apex class.I need the code example for that

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. I think you may have added the wrong tag to your question here, but it's hard to tell with so little information in your question. Please [edit] your question to include the code you already have, as well as some examples of the situation(s) that you want to handle. The official documentation is also a good place to start looking. [Building a Custom Controllers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_custom.htm) will probably help, which should lead you to the `ApexPages` class.

Comment: I think there may be a mismatch of expectations here, to extend Derek's notes. We don't provide solutions or code, but we're happy to help with *specific issues* in work that you've done.

Comment: I understand your concern David.I am just asking how to capture ids from a url and sent it to a apex class .I modified my question  as well.If you have any answer please provide

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? How to retrieve data from URL parameters is [thoroughly documented](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_System_PageReference_getParameters.htm).

Answer (score 5):

Like I hinted at in my comment, the [Building a Custom Controller](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_custom.htm) page in the official Visualforce Developer's Guide gives you a good approach. It does, however, require some understanding of how URLs work.

As a short refresher, everything after the `?` in a URL is part of the *Query String*.
A Query string can hold multiple variables, of the form  `<variable name>=<value>` and separated by an ampersand `&`.

From that page, we see the following query

```
account = [SELECT Id, Name, Site FROM Account
           WHERE Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];
```

`ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')` is the important part here.

If you look at [the documentation on the ApexPages class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_apexpages.htm#apex_System_ApexPages_currentPage), the `currentPage()` method is documented

> ### currentPage()
>
> Returns the current page's PageReference.
>
> #### Signature
>
> public System.PageReference currentPage()
>
> #### Return Value
>
> Type: System.PageReference

Then, after following a few more links, we arrive at [the documentation for the getParameters() method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_System_PageReference_getParameters.htm)

`getParameters()` returns a `Map<String, String>` where the key of the map is the name of the query string parameter/variable, and the value is...well, the associated value.

If my url were `/myPage?id=001000000000123&foo=bar`
`getParameters()` would return the equivalent of:

```
new Map<String, String>{
    'id' => '001000000000123',
    'foo' => 'bar'
}
```

So the flow here is:

- Ask for the current page to get a `pageReference`
- Ask for the parameters from the `pageReference` to get a `Map<String, String>`
- Use the map's `get()` method to extract your target information from your URL

In your specific situation, since a comma is not the variable delimiter, you'd get a string containing both of your target Ids. Splitting those Ids out (and doing so in a way that doesn't break your code when trying to process a single Id) is beyond the scope of this question. I'd encourage you to try to take things from here, and reference the Apex Developer's guide when you next get stuck.